# Function generation; change defaults of other functions (partial)

Tags: r, partial, pryr

I have the need for a function generator that takes another function and any arguments of that function and sets new defaults.  I thought @hadley's `pryr::partial` was that magic function.  It does exactly what I want except you can't then change that new default.  So here I can change `sep` in my new `paste` function but not the new default of `collapse = "_BAR_"`.  How can I make `partial` perform this way (i.e., default to `collapse = "_BAR_"` but enable setting it to `collapse = NULL` if desired)?  If this is not possible with `partial` is there a way to rewrite the code for `partial` to do this: https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/partial.r

```
library(pryr)
.paste <- pryr::partial(paste, collapse = "_FOO_")

.paste(1:5)
.paste(1:5, LETTERS[1:5], sep="_BAR_")
.paste(1:5, collapse=NULL)

> .paste(1:5)
[1] "1_FOO_2_FOO_3_FOO_4_FOO_5"

> .paste(1:5, LETTERS[1:5], sep="_BAR_")
[1] "1_BAR_A_FOO_2_BAR_B_FOO_3_BAR_C_FOO_4_BAR_D_FOO_5_BAR_E"

> .paste(1:5, collapse=NULL)
Error in paste(collapse = "_FOO_", ...) : 
  formal argument "collapse" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: Perhaps, also, `Defaults::setDefaults` could be helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`partial` is good for fixing certain parameter values, but if you want to change defaults, you might consider a different strategy. This would work

```
.paste <- paste
formals(.paste)$collapse <- "_FOO_"
```

This changes the parameters to the function

```
args(.paste)
# function (..., sep = " ", collapse = "_FOO_") 
# NULL
```

Then you can do

```
.paste(1:5)
# [1] "1_FOO_2_FOO_3_FOO_4_FOO_5"
.paste(1:5, LETTERS[1:5], sep="_BAR_")
# [1] "1_BAR_A_FOO_2_BAR_B_FOO_3_BAR_C_FOO_4_BAR_D_FOO_5_BAR_E"
.paste(1:5, collapse=NULL)
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Comment: How about removing the default altogether?

Comment: (to answer my own comment) To remove a default, it appears to be sufficient to do `formals(.paste)$collapse <-  alist(dummy=)$dummy`. Now `.paste` has no default for `collapse`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a canned function taking @MrFlick's great response and putting it into a function for future searchers:

```
hijack <- function(FUN, ...){

    .FUN <- FUN

    args <- list(...)
    invisible(lapply(seq_along(args), function(i) {
        formals(.FUN)[[names(args)[i]]] <<- args[[i]]
    }))
    .FUN
}
```

**# Now Try It**

```
.paste <- hijack(paste, collapse = "_FOO_")

.paste(1:5)
.paste(1:5, LETTERS[1:5], sep="_BAR_")
.paste(1:5, collapse=NULL)
```

**Yielding**

```
> .paste(1:5)
[1] "1_FOO_2_FOO_3_FOO_4_FOO_5"

> .paste(1:5, LETTERS[1:5], sep="_BAR_")
[1] "1_BAR_A_FOO_2_BAR_B_FOO_3_BAR_C_FOO_4_BAR_D_FOO_5_BAR_E"

> .paste(1:5, collapse=NULL)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just write a simple wrapper

```
.paste <- function(..., collapse = "_FOO_"){paste(..., collapse = collapse)}
```

which gives

```
> .paste <- function(..., collapse = "_FOO_"){paste(..., collapse = collapse)}
> .paste(1:5)
[1] "1_FOO_2_FOO_3_FOO_4_FOO_5"
> .paste(1:5, collapse = NULL)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Comment: True but the idea was to make it have the same function arguments.

Comment: And this doesn't how?  You can still pass in `sep` if you want.