# override default parameters in a function called by another function

Tags: r, function

I run a `mirt` model and the results `summary` says:

```
In GPFoblq(L, Tmat = Tmat, normalize = normalize, eps = eps, maxit = maxit,  :
  convergence not obtained in GPFoblq. 1000 iterations used.
```

I would like to set maxit to 2000. And I would like to try to suggestion in [Function generation; change defaults of other functions (partial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355310/function-generation-change-defaults-of-other-functions-partial). However, I cannot find the `GPFoblq` function.

```
> GPFoblq()
Error: could not find function "GPFoblq"
```

I am confused -- how did `mirt` call `GPFoblq`? And how can I override the `maxit` value?

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `library(mirt); GPFoblq()` ? I am not sure how to give a reproducible example as it is not error....

Comment: You give a reproducible example by **including the data you used and the code you ran** to produce the result that you didn't like. You didn't even include your code. Also, you show an error message relating to this `GPFoblq` function but then you say there's no error. This is confusing. Anyway, I believe the answer will be that you need to use the `control` argument in `mirt`. Please review the link I posted if you need further help understand the *Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example* that StackOverflow **requires** for this category of questions.

Comment: `mirt` package may have attached but not imported another package. Typing GPFoblq() will not do anything useful. Look at the DESCRIPTION file from package mirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `maxit` you need to use the control argument in `mirt`:

```
require(mirt)
data <- expand.table(LSAT7)

(mod1 <- mirt(data, 1,control=list(maxit=10000)))
```

> ```
> Iteration: 28, Log-Lik: -2658.805, Max-Change: 0.00010
> Call:
> mirt(data = data, model = 1, control = list(maxit = 10000))
>
> Full-information item factor analysis with 1 factor(s).
> Converged within 1e-04 tolerance after 28 EM iterations.
> mirt version: 1.18 
> M-step optimizer: BFGS 
> EM acceleration: Ramsay
> Number of rectangular quadrature: 61
>
> Log-likelihood = -2658.805
> AIC = 5337.61; AICc = 5337.833
> BIC = 5386.688; SABIC = 5354.927
> G2 (21) = 31.7, p = 0.0628
> RMSEA = 0.023, CFI = 0.939, TLI = 0.924
> ```

Regarding the 2nd question about `GPFoblq` -- it's not in `mirt.R` but apparently in one of the other source files or the dependencies that function was used. You can explore the package or it's Wiki to find out.

https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/blob/master/R

https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/wiki

or, as @42 mentioned, you may find out in the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answers -- figured out control after your pointer above -- but won't get the dependencies part without your explanation, and also help me to get an idea on how to give a reproducible example! (I will delete this comment in 24 hours to comply with the commenting rule)

Comment: @ceoec Happy to help :) By dependencies I just meant that it's possible that `mirt` may use another package in its code and that package may have used the function you were asking about. So it's possible that it's only being indirectly used by `mirt`. If you want to find out read the files on the GitHub site for `mirt`.

Comment: Yep will read the GitHub site. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ceoec see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on hints on how to make reproducible examples. Don't worry about removing the comments, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I just learned from the author of `mirt` that `GPFoblq` was called in `summary` but not `mirt`. Therefore my question does not make any sense.... Should I delete the question?